# How to find the max number of a average?

Tags: coldfusion

Im new to using coldfusion and I'm trying to figure out how i can output the max number of a average. Right now i can find the average for a specific department, but how would I from that data get the max number from that list and display the max average number?

here is my code

```
<tr>
        <td>#csedept_name#</td>
        <td><div align="right">#totalcount#</div></td>
        <td><div align="right"><cfif totalstars eq ''>&ndash;<cfelse>#totalstars#</cfif></div></td>
        <td><div align="right"><cfif totalstarsgiven eq ''>&ndash;<cfelse>#totalstarsgiven#</cfif></div></td>
        <td><div align="right"><cfif totalstars eq ''>&ndash;<cfelse><cfset avgstars = totalstars / totalcount>#DecimalFormat(avgstars)#</cfif></div></td>
    </tr>
        <cfset countEmployees = countEmployees + totalcount>
        <cfif totalstarsgiven neq ''><cfset countStarsGiven = countStarsGiven + totalstarsgiven></cfif>
        <cfif totalstars neq ''>
            <cfset countStarsReceived = countStarsReceived + totalstars>
            <cfset countStarAverage = countStarAverage + avgstars>
        </cfif>
.....
    <th><div align="right">#countEmployees#</div></th>
    <th><div align="right">#countStarsReceived#</div></th>
    <th><div align="right">#countStarsGiven#</div></th>
    <th><div align="right">#avgstars#</div></th> //here to display the max of the average
```

Here is the query code:

```
<h1><cfoutput>#self#</cfoutput></h1>
    <cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="GetDepartments">
        SELECT * FROM CSEReduxDepts
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="GroupStars">
        SELECT execoffice_status, employeedept, COUNT(*) as 'totalstars'
        FROM CSEReduxResponses
        WHERE execoffice_status = 1
        GROUP BY execoffice_status, employeedept
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="GetTotalStars">
        SELECT *
        FROM GroupStars, GetDepartments
        WHERE GroupStars.employeedept = GetDepartments.csedept_id
    </cfquery>

<cfif GetTotalStars.RecordCount gt 0>
    <cfquery datasource="PhoneList" name="GetAllData">
        SELECT dept.csedept_id, COUNT(*) as 'totalcount'
        FROM employee, dept
        WHERE employee.dept_id = dept.dept_id
            AND employee.emp_status = 1
            AND dept.csedept_id is not null
        GROUP BY dept.csedept_id
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="GetDepartmentTotalEmployeesCount">
        SELECT *
        FROM GetAllData, GetDepartments
        WHERE GetAllData.csedept_id = GetDepartments.csedept_id
    </cfquery>



<cfquery name="joinQuery" dbtype="query" >
SELECT *
FROM GetTotalStars
WHERE GetTotalStars.csedept_id = -1
</cfquery>

<cfset QueryAddRow(joinQuery)>

<cfquery name="GetUnion" dbtype="query" >
SELECT *
FROM GetDepartmentTotalEmployeesCount, GetTotalStars
WHERE GetDepartmentTotalEmployeesCount.csedept_id = GetTotalStars.csedept_id

UNION

SELECT GetDepartmentTotalEmployeesCount.*, joinQuery.*
FROM GetDepartmentTotalEmployeesCount, joinQuery
WHERE GetDepartmentTotalEmployeesCount.csedept_id NOT IN (#ValueList(GetTotalStars.csedept_id)#)
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="GroupStarsGiven">
    SELECT execoffice_status, submitterdept, COUNT(*) as 'totalstarsgiven'
    FROM CSEReduxResponses
    WHERE execoffice_status = 1
    GROUP BY execoffice_status, submitterdept
</cfquery>

<cfquery dbtype="query" name="GetTotalStarsGiven">
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupStarsGiven, GetDepartments
    WHERE GroupStarsGiven.submitterdept = GetDepartments.csedept_id
</cfquery>


<cfquery name="joinQuery2" dbtype="query" >
SELECT *
FROM GetTotalStarsGiven
WHERE GetTotalStarsGiven.csedept_id = -1
</cfquery>

<cfset QueryAddRow(joinQuery2)>

<cfquery name="GetUnion2" dbtype="query" >
SELECT *
FROM GetUnion, GetTotalStarsGiven
WHERE GetUnion.csedept_id = GetTotalStarsGiven.csedept_id

UNION

SELECT GetUnion.*, joinQuery2.*
FROM GetUnion, joinQuery2
WHERE GetUnion.csedept_id NOT IN (#ValueList(GetTotalStarsGiven.csedept_id)#)
ORDER BY csedept_name ASC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Okay, so you've shown us the output of the variables but where are they coming from? Is there a query, list, or what? Please, show us more code.

Comment: I have added the query.

Comment: Now I am regretting asking you this. I highly suggest what you rethink your queries. I suggest looking into the `JOIN` statement and I also suggest not using `*` and you should look into using `<cfqueryparam>` Now that we go that out of the way I will tell you my approach to the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can do this with sql.  The general idea is

```
select dept, max(number) maxnumber, avg(number) avgnumber
from department join 
(select deptid, number
from department
where clause
) temp on department.deptid = temp.deptid
where clause
group by dept
```

Make sure the two where clauses are the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to skin this cat. I apologize if you like cats.

First, you can do it the way Dan suggested. Simple enough, right?

Second, and I do not recommend it over the other.

```
<cfset maxNum = ArrayMax(query['columnname']) />
```

but it is an option

Comment: Plus 1 for the cat reference only.  Change your answer to ArrayMax(query['columnname']) and others may follow.

Comment: wouldn't this only work if 'colunmname' exist, since avgstars is not a colunm?